# How to resolve segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault while printing out the output in the terminal. I searched online. And understand that this fault is because of accessing a memory location that is not allowed to access. But I am required to use pointers as in my code. So any ideas to resolve this issue.

Function:

```
void mix_dataset(array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset) {
size_t len = array_X_dataset.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    size_t swap_index = rand() % len;  // Random number between 0 and len-1.
    if (i == swap_index)
        continue;

    array<int, 20> data_point{  };
    data_point = array_X_dataset[i];
    array_X_dataset[i] = array_X_dataset[swap_index];
    array_X_dataset[swap_index] = data_point;
    int Y = array_Y_dataset[i];
    array_Y_dataset[i] = array_Y_dataset[swap_index];
    array_Y_dataset[swap_index] = Y;
}
}
```

main:

```
 mix_dataset(array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset);
 int* array_Y_set = new int[5430];
 int** array_X_set = new int* [5430];
 for (int i = 0; i < 5430; i++) {
        array_X_set[i] = new int[20];
    }
    // copy contents of the mixed std::arrays into plain arrays  
    for (int i = 0; i < 5430; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            array_X_set[i][j] = array_X_dataset[i][j];
        array_Y_set[i] = array_Y_dataset[i];
    }
      printf("printout the whole dataset after random mixing:\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < 5430; i++) {
          printf(" %d ", i);
          for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
              printf(" %d ", array_X_set[i + j * 5430]);
          printf(" %d ", array_Y_set[i]);
          printf("\n");
  
      }
```

Comment: `array_X_set[i + j * 5430]` So what happened here? Why not `array_X_set[...][....]`?

Comment: You are accessing `array_X_set ` as if it was a 1D array[20*5430], while you allocate it as an array of pointers [5430]

Comment: `std::array` does grant access to the underlying array. Could be that " I am required to use pointers as in my code" is based on a misunderstanding

Comment: At least tell us *where* the violation occurs !

Comment: @YvesDaoust the code printout this statement `printout the whole dataset after random mixing:` Then it says segmentation fault

Comment: Weird that you don't see the next " %d " printf. But the problem is with `array_X_set[i + j * 5430]`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But when compiling the same code with your modify in Visual studio and Linux. Both tries gave me two different outputs. even I used the same code. Could you explain why ?

Comment: My "modify" ??? I did not modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

`printf(" %d ", array_X_set[i + j * 5430]);`

-->

`printf(" %d ", array_X_set[i][j]);`

Comment: Thank you for reply, your solution removed the fault. But when compiling the same code with your modify in Visual studio and Linux. Both tries gave me two different outputs. even I used the same code. Could you explain why ?

Comment: That almost certainly is because of the random numbers, right? How do you seed rand?  Add `srand (98837);` as first call in your main function.

Comment: I already put srand(3) in both codes. But still the same problem.

Comment: To debug, I would still first check the random number sequence. It is not 100% guaranteed that rand will return the same sequences on different compilers. Just printout the values of 'rand()' to see. If this IS the problem, there are much better random number generators that also actually consistent on different systems.